# How can handle screen rotation whilst executing a HTTP post?

Tags: java, android

I have a method which executes a HTTP post...

When the user rotates the device during this process, it causes an ANR.

Here is my code...

```
public void uploadTransactions(View v)
{
    final ProgressDialog prog;

    try
    {
        // disable screen rotation
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

        // setup progress dialog
        prog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        prog.setTitle("Uploading Transactions");
        prog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        prog.setIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
        prog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        prog.setCancelable(false);
        prog.show();

        // setup thread for the sync
        Thread syncThread = new Thread();
        syncThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                String result = "";
                String currentFileContents = "";
                GetByREST gbr = new GetByREST();

                String URL = //url for ReST service
                String URLparam = "";
                String accountNo = //authorisation info
                String emailAddress = //authorisation info
                String password = //authorisation info

                try
                {
                    // loop through the files
                    File file = new File(SALES_DIRECTORY);
                    for (File thisFile : file.listFiles())
                    {
                        currentFileContents = readTransactions(thisFile);

                        updateProgress(prog, "Uploading " + thisFile.getName());
                        result = gbr.getRestOutput(URL, URLparam, accountNo, emailAddress, password, "3", new StringEntity(currentFileContents));

                    }

                    prog.dismiss();//dismiss the dialog
                    // ...re-enable rotation
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    messageBox("uploadTransactions: syncThread", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        syncThread.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        messageBox("uploadTransactions", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This works fine if the screen is in portrait but, when in landscape, the orientation returns to portrait and causes an ANR. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're probably (need more code to see..) this in your Activity as a random method.

You're activity re-starts on orientation changes. 
Not only this, but also when a user shuts down your app now, you have no way of being sure that your upload continues.

Instead, you want to start up a service which isn't bound to your Activity's lifecycle. 
There are enough tutorials for this, now you know what to look for. 
You could also give the library RoboSpice a try which does exactly this.

ps. Using an AsyncTask will not solve this, the AsyncTask itself will still be bound to your Activity's lifecycle.

Comment: I only want to add that you can check this article dealing specifically with AsyncTasks and changing screen orientation: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: True, but this article doesn't focus on problems that aren't directly in his question. The upload might take minutes and the whole activity might already be closed by the user and Destroyed by the system. HTTP stuff goes into a Service, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Add this line to your activity in the manifest

```
<activity
....
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

Try using [Asyc](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask3) for your data downloading

Comment: Bad advise to use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need to decouple the network access from your UI. According to [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html), you could move the UI specifics in a retained `Fragment` (call `setRetainInstance(true);`), start an AsyncTask from that Fragment and .... that's it!

However, I have a felling your ANR is not actually caused by this as you might be doing something else in the UI thread - probably some networking stuff. I'm not sure if `updateProgress(prog, "Uploading " + thisFile.getName());` does happen on UI thread (as it should). Posting more code from what you're doing in your activity might reveal this.

Answer (score 0):

This situation happens because your  thread tries to work for a destroyed  activity or context. try to intrupt your thread in

```
onDestroy()
```

method and be sure  not to call your handler while doing it.

Screen orientation change destroys your current activity and creates it again.

I hope it helps.